# Zebra stripes ignoring hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

Say I have a table whose rows can be dynamically assigned `.hidden` classes. Rows with that class are hidden via CSS. The rows are also styled with alternating colours, like so:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: $light-grey;
}
```

However, I want every even, *unhidden* row to be shaded. So hidden rows are not counted when `:nth-child(even)` is applied, and the pattern appears consistent. The following is my immediate attempt, but it doesn't do what I'm hoping for.

```
tr:not(.hidden):nth-child(even) {
    background-color: $light-grey;
}
```

`:nth-child()` is simply referring to the rows' original indices, not the current selection scope from `tr:not(.hidden)`. The two are simply 'filtered through' on top of one another.

Is there a `:nth-of-scope/selection()` (or simply `:nth()`) meta class in CSS? Are there any equivalents or alternate methods?

Or must I resort to Javascript?

(I should say that I can also use jQuery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in pure CSS as adding `display:none` or `visibility:none` doesn't remove the elements from the DOM, which is what CSS uses.

As a result, you will need to add a little JavaScript (which runs once the page has loaded) to do this, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/ox3wancg/)

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr"), // Select whichever ones you need
    count = 0; // Counter for the non-hidden ones

for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {    
    if(!trs[i].classList.contains("hidden") && (count++)%2 == 0) { // Odd ones
        trs[i].style.background = "black";
    } else if(!trs[i].classList.contains("hidden")) { // Even ones
        trs[i].style.background = "lightgrey";
    }
}
```

Comment: @kornieff You're wrong. Your answer doesn't address the issue asked about in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out using jQuery is much simpler than any sort of CSS hack:

```
rows = $('table tbody tr');
rows.find('tr:visible:odd').css('background-color', '#f7f7f7');
```

And to specify styles for both even and odd:

```
rows.find('tr:visible').each(function(i) {
    if (i%2) {
        $(this).css('background', '#f7f7f7');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
    };
});
```

I know, I've answered by own question—I should have made it clear that I can use jQuery!

I just wish `:visible` and `:even` would hurry up and make it into the CSS standard.

Comment: Just noting, this is the same approach as the one I answered with but using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I've just managed to solve this by just adding an extra `<tr>` element with `display: none;` set (via CSS in my case but could use a style attribute) when a block of hidden rows has an odd number of elements. This won't meet every use case, but for cases where you're using multiple rows to create expanding tables it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible with pure CSS. Using `display:none;` and `visibility:hidden;` the items still exist in the DOM and so the table background color is displayed incorrectly. You can get this to work using JQuery `remove()`  You can see my simple example on [js.fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdddxcu/)

Comment: Yes. However, I definitely don't want to remove the elements—they should be able to be unhidden just as before.

Answer (score 0):

Pure **CSS** (**no JS**) solution:

The trick is to hide a row with different tag, not class. "ul/li" tags must go. In my example I use "del" tag to hide.

```css
.list div:nth-of-type(odd) { background: ghostwhite; }
.list del { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <del>4</del>
  <div>5</div>
  <del>6</del>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is asking about how to do zebra stripes when elements are hidden using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` with *the same tag*, i.e. all divs. You are using a different tag

Comment: @ZachSaucier Right, this isn't what the question asked for, but only because I hadn't considered this approach. Although it's clearly a bad hack, it actually works… just change the tag name instead of the class, causing the DOM (and CSS indices) to be rebuilt…